# Crystal Reports and Windows 7 - Exporting to Excel and does a "double row" format

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

We (a company) have an application that creates a report using crystal reports. This program then gives us the option to export that partcular report into an excel document. We recently upgraded our reporting server to SQL 2008, which was previously SQL 2003. In doing so some, not all, users are having an issue where the exporting of said report causes excel to place double rows for each row data. This causes issues since we use macros to combine these reports. We have noticed that users with a higher level of access are not affected by this but we have not been able to definnativley prove this. Has anyone else encountered this issue that maybe they know how to address it. Any comments or help would be much appreciated.

*PS: The application in question was created somewhere around 2003.

Comment: You mention these are Crystal Reports, this is a different reporting product to (Microsoft) Reporting Services, with which you have also tagged the question. Is Reporting Services actually involved?

Comment: the answer is here... its a issue that was hard to solve... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330632/1291937

Answer (score 0):

Given that this problem presented itself after your server upgrade, I'd look at the queries being used in the Crystal Reports files. It seems like something happened in the upgrade that has broken the queries being used. Since you say that users with lower access rights might be the only ones affected, I'd start by looking at how these access rights are being applied to the report.

It could also be a formatting problem in the Crystal Report - these tend to cause problems with Excel exports pretty easily, but this seems less likely since you're seeing entirely duplicate rows.

It's hard to say for certain with the information in the post right now, but in my experience problems like these are generally the result of a flawed query in Crystal.