# export Crystal report to Excel (empty rows)

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

I am trying to export a report to excel. When I export my report to Excel I am getting blank rows between each detail section. I assume this is because I have a context menu in form of a normal text element which overlies the "normal" text elements.

Does anybody have any advice on how I can stop the blank rows occurring? Is it possible to suppress a text element only when it is exported to Excel?

Thanks!

Comment: shrink your fields as much as posible

Comment: how do you export to excel?? is it by using data sets(data tables)??

Comment: with the export-function when the report is open

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it compact.

It should be no space between each object. You should set every object on the same row has the same height and every object on column has the same width.

When there's a space between objects, it will create a cell on excel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that already, but what can I do with the text element which overlies the others?

Comment: what kind of overlie? does it make another text not created on excel cell? could you share the pic? 
try to adhere each nearest object.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 articles from Ken Hamady that might be helpfull:
http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/231
http://www.kenhamady.com/news0506.shtml  (scroll to the bottom of the page)

Another option , if you are working with tabular data is to use a report extension like it is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hk6FJ1dvb4
This approach will use the Crystal report as a datasource and will export the data from a grid with much better formatting. The video is using a 3rd party tool, but it is free  -  http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:

```
Public Shared Sub ExportDataSetToExcel(ByVal ds As DataTable, ByVal filename As String)
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        response.Clear()
        response.Buffer = True
        response.Charset = ""
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
          Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                Dim dg As New DataGrid()
                dg.DataSource = ds
                dg.DataBind()
                dg.RenderControl(htw)
                response.Charset = "UTF-8"
                response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())
                response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
                response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've solved this issue, after a long time researching. Make the fields inside the details section fill the whole height of the section... no spaces between fields and top and bottom edges.

[image: this]

instead of this

[image]